# How to send PHP variables and retrieve them with Jquery (without echo)?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm building a search function to retrieve XML data for a google map.

In addition to that, I want to display how many results were actually found.

I thought about doing an echo inside the actual document, however that might mess with my marker data. How would I take a PHP variable and retrieve it in Jquery after a success call?

If my PHP looked like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

And Jquery like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MapSearchxml.php",
        data: {
            dataFromDate: FromDate,
            //lalala
            dataHasPatio: HasPatio
        },
        beforeSend: function (html) { // this happens before actual call
            $("#results").html('Please Wait');
            $("#searchresults").show();
            $(".phpFromDate").html(FromDate);
        },
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

        //Success?
        },
        dataType: 'xml'
    });
```

Comment: You'll need to "echo" something. In this case it will be the *combined* XML document.

Comment: Dump to file and use apache's mod x-sendfile probably - no not really :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might find it easier to  create array in php and send JSON. At client is easy to loop over response object/array

```
$output=array('status'=>'', 'results'=>array());
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if( $num_rows){ 
  $output['status']='ok';
  /* push row data to $output['results'][]; in while loop*/
}else{
  $output['status']= 'No results';
}

echo json_encode( $output);
```

Then in jQuery:

```
success:function( data){
  if (data.status != 'No results' ){
      /* count array length*/
      var count= data.results.length;
      /* loop over data.results array*/
  }
}

/* change dataType to "json"*/
```

I forgot about `count` and added it in jQuery...can also add a `count` property to the `$output` php array and use `$num_rows` to populate

Answer (score 1):

Just trying out a JSON example for you, this has echo but you can do complex things with it?

Not sure if that is what your after? I get that you don't want to do echo on each variable, and you wont if using JSON.

```
<?php
$simple = 'simple string';
$complex = array('more', 'complex', 'object', array('foo', 'bar'));
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var simple = '<?php echo $simple; ?>';
var complex = <?php echo json_encode($complex); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Show output, and make this a jsonp I suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You see, what AJAX gets on success is an html code. If you AJAX a complete html page you will get it back, starting with `<html>` and ending with `</html>`. You can just make a special markap on your return html data, like `[sepcial_info : 'INFO']`   or somthing and then just to filter it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I needed a bit to decipher your question, probably I'm still wrong, let's try:

What you try to do is not technically possible with what you have in mind. In short: If you do one Ajax request, you return one response. The moment the `success` function is called, your PHP script is already gone. So you can only pass one return value.

However what you can do is, that you make that return value a nested one, e.g. containing two parts:

1. The XML document you already returned
2. The count

That is probably your solution. If you ask how, I would add the count as a namespaced value to the XML and then process it with javascript.

As you have not shown any code here, I can not give a quick example (and I leave that as a pointer for your future questions) for your case. Add a namespace element, like an attribute is pretty simple with [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) in PHP.